# Validate if value exists before insert row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query where I send a TableType who have columns `EmpKey` and `TaskId` like:

```
  @AssignNotificationTableType [dbo].[udf_TaskNotification] READONLY

INSERT INTO [TaskNotification] ([TaskId], [EmpKey])
    SELECT
        [ANT].[TaskId], [E].[EmpKey]
    FROM 
        @AssignNotificationTableType AS [ANT]
    INNER JOIN 
        [Employee] AS [E] ON [ANT].[EmpGuid] = [E].[EmpGuid]
```

So my table looks like this:

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+
|          TaskNotificationId          |                TaskId                | EmpKey |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+

| EEE3D3F8-F190-E811-841F-C81F66DACA6A | D0440DEB-404C-4006-870F-E95BFFA840E0 |     44 |
| EFE3D3F8-F190-E811-841F-C81F66DACA6A | D0440DEB-404C-4006-870F-E95BFFA840E0 |     49 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+
```

As you can see two items have same `TaskId` but different `Empkey`, so suppose if I send again same `TaskId` `D0440DEB-404C-4006-870F-E95BFFA840E0` I want to insert only row only if EmpKey does not exist in that TaskId

So if I send something like:

```
+--+--------------------------------------+--------+
|  |                TaskId                | EmpKey |
+--+--------------------------------------+--------+
|  | D0440DEB-404C-4006-870F-E95BFFA840E0 |     44 |
|  | D0440DEB-404C-4006-870F-E95BFFA840E0 |     49 |
|  | D0440DEB-404C-4006-870F-E95BFFA840E0 |     54 |
+--+--------------------------------------+--------+
```

It will only insert last row, because `EmpKey`  54 does not exist in that `TaskId`

I try to do in `WHERE` clause with `NOT IN` as:

```
INSERT INTO [TaskNotification] ([TaskId], [EmpKey])
    SELECT
        [ANT].[TaskId], [E].[EmpKey]
    FROM 
        @AssignNotificationTableType AS [ANT]
    INNER JOIN 
        [Employee] AS [E] ON [ANT].[EmpGuid] = [E].[EmpGuid]
    WHERE 
        [E].[EmpKey] NOT IN (SELECT EmpKey
                             FROM [TaskNotification]
                             WHERE TaskId = (SELECT TaskId 
                                             FROM @AssignNotificationTableType))
```

But when I run it, it just don't insert anything. What am I doing wrong? Regards

Comment: Why are you using "WHERE TaskId = (SELECT TaskId FROM @AssignNotificationTableType)" ?

Comment: If I don't use it, it get all Employees of employee table or I'm wrong? If I remove it it's just same result, it does not insert anything @AlvaroParra

Comment: Your last subquery is going to fail if you send more than a single row in your table variable. You should use a NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the target table as a left join to the select statement:

```
INSERT INTO [TaskNotification]
(
     [TaskId]
    , [EmpKey]
)
 SELECT
       [ANT].[TaskId]
     , [E].[EmpKey]
       FROM @AssignNotificationTableType AS [ANT]
           INNER JOIN [Employee] AS [E] ON [ANT].[EmpGuid] = [E].[EmpGuid]
           LEFT JOIN [TaskNotification] AS [TN] ON [TN].[TaskId] = [ANT].[TaskId]
               AND [TN].[EmpKey] = [E].[EmpKey]
       WHERE [TN].[PK] IS NULL -- PK stands for the primary key column 
       -- (or first column in of a multiple columns pk)
```

Please note, however, this in a multithreaded environment such query might fail - For more information, read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48741905/3094533) and Dan Guzman's blog post it links to.

Comment: what is PK field into last where clause?  `WHERE [TN].[PK] IS NULL`?

Comment: I try this but I still have same problem

Comment: Shouldn't "[TN].[EmpKey] = [ANT].[EmpKey]" be "[TN].[EmpKey] = [E].[EmpKey]"?

Comment: I'm really confused there... I don't have an idea what is  `[TN].[PK] `@UnhandledExcepSean

Comment: Yes, "[TN].[EmpKey] = [ANT].[EmpKey]" be "[TN].[EmpKey] = [E].[EmpKey]". And [TN].[PK] - Replace `PK` with the primary key column of the `TN` table (any non-nullable column will do, the primary key is also indexed so it will have a better execution plan.