# Update value if exist or insert in SQL with C# linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I have this code which is working fine and I update a value if exists or insert if not

```
List<KodikosProtimisis> newList = new List<KodikosProtimisis>();
newList.Add(new KodikosProtimisis { Kodikos = "100", Perigrafi = "Description", TaricTiposMetrou = "103" });
newList.Add(new KodikosProtimisis { Kodikos = "110", Perigrafi = "Description", TaricTiposMetrou = "112" });
newList.Add(new KodikosProtimisis { Kodikos = "420", Perigrafi = "Description", TaricTiposMetrou = "112" });
.
.
.
(more values)

string connectionString = Configuration.Parameters.Config.ConnectionString;

string query = @"IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.KodikosProtimisis WHERE Kodikos = @kodikos and DiasafistisId=@diasafistisId)
                        UPDATE dbo.KodikosProtimisis 
                        SET Kodikos = @kodikos, DiasafistisId=@diasafistisId,Perigrafi=@perigrafi,TaricTiposMetrou = @taricTiposMetrou
                        WHERE Kodikos = @kodikos and DiasafistisId=@diasafistisId or DiasafistisId is null
                    ELSE
                        INSERT INTO dbo.KodikosProtimisis(Kodikos, Perigrafi,TaricTiposMetrou, DiasafistisId) VALUES(@kodikos, @perigrafi,@taricTiposMetrou, @diasafistisId);";

foreach (var person in newList)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        //δίνουμε τις παραμέτρους στο ερώτημα μας 
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@kodikos", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = person.Kodikos;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@perigrafi", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = person.Perigrafi;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@diasafistisId", SqlDbType.Int, 100).Value = DefaultDiasafistis.DiasafistisDefault.Id;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@taricTiposMetrou", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 150).Value = person.TaricTiposMetrou;

        conn.Open();
        int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

With this code I manage to do the work with only one query to the SQL, but I was wondering if there is an easier or more elegant way to do it.

For example if I could use linq and lambda expressions (which I don't have much experience with).

I want (if it's possible) to remove the query and put something that I can control more easy and most important to maintain it easily if something changes, for example database design or massively change something in the existing values.

EDIT: 
I really don't understand why I have the negative votes. 
I give a specific code that already works and I ask if there is a better way.

Comment: if you want to write with LINQ you have to use [EF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/) or any other [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)

Comment: Your SQL script still can be rewritten in terms of `MERGE` operator, [more info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL))

Comment: @AlexLarionov yes but I already wrote I want to avoid using simple sql queries

Comment: @styx I already have linq queries in my program , but I don't know if and how can I rewrite this using linq

Comment: @rippergr just break down to small queries, I.E "IF EXISTS.." can be replaced with `Any()`

Comment: @styx Can you give me an example based on my code?

Comment: [There's a better way to do it in TSQL...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52780490/3094533)

Comment: @ZoharPeled What is the point to change an already working code with another. The link you gave me just shows another way to execute a query. There is no error handling as they mention.

Comment: @rippergr What ZoharPeled is suggesting you is to wrap the whole thing in an atomic transaction that is not something you are doing in your code.

Comment: Because it's a better code, both from the thread safty perspective and from the perfomance perspective.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer.
Here is the code that uses linq and lambda expressions

```
        List<KodikosProtimisis> newListKodikosProtimisis = new List<KodikosProtimisis>();
                    newListKodikosProtimisis.Add(new KodikosProtimisis { Kodikos = "100", Perigrafi = "Δασμός τρίτων χωρών έναντι όλων (erga omnes)", TaricTiposMetrou = "103" });
                    newListKodikosProtimisis.Add(new KodikosProtimisis { Kodikos = "110", Perigrafi = "Αυτόνομη δασμολογική αναστολή έναντι όλων (erga omnes) (προσωρινή αναστολή των αυτόνομων δασμών για ορισμένα εμπορεύματα του αγροτικού, χημικού, αεροναυπηγικού και του ηλεκτρονικού τομέα)", TaricTiposMetrou = "112" });
                    newListKodikosProtimisis.Add(new KodikosProtimisis { Kodikos = "420", Perigrafi = "Ποσόστωση τελωνειακής ένωσης", TaricTiposMetrou = "112" });
                    newListKodikosProtimisis.Add(new KodikosProtimisis { Kodikos = "422", Perigrafi = "Ποσόστωση τελωνειακής ένωσης", TaricTiposMetrou = "112" });
    .
    .
    .
    more values
                    foreach (var kodikosProtimisis in newListKodikosProtimisis)
                    {

                        using (Ektel db = new Ektel(EktelDataContextManager.ConnectionString))
                        {

                            var qry = db.KodikosProtimisis.Where(x => x.Kodikos == kodikosProtimisis.Kodikos).FirstOrDefault();

                            if (qry != null)
                            {
                                // The value exists .Update
                                qry.Kodikos = kodikosProtimisis.Kodikos;
                                qry.Perigrafi = kodikosProtimisis.Perigrafi;
                                qry.TaricTiposMetrou = kodikosProtimisis.TaricTiposMetrou;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //The value doesnt exist.Insert.
                                db.KodikosProtimisis.InsertOnSubmit(new KodikosProtimisis
                                {
                                    Kodikos = kodikosProtimisis.Kodikos,
                                    Perigrafi = kodikosProtimisis.Perigrafi,
                                    TaricTiposMetrou = kodikosProtimisis.TaricTiposMetrou
                                });
                            }

                        db.SubmitChanges();
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

By using Entity Framework, you can use [`AddOrUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.migrations.idbsetextensions.addorupdate?view=entity-framework-5.0.0) method.

You need include `System.Data.Entity.Migrations;` in your using statements.

But please note that it is **not atomic** and it is **not threadsafe**.

Comment: Sorry but I think this is worse than the one I use :)

Comment: @rippergr There is no reason for you to be sorry :) I don't know what you mean by worse?! Based on what you asked: "if there is an easier or more elegant way....something that I can control more easy and most important to maintain it easily if something changes" and since this answer suggests to use linqtoentities along with strongly typed entities, it definitely provides an easier and more elegant way to do what you want and it absolutely makes change management easier! Since you do not need to use non-strongly typed dirty strings to generate TSQL anymore.

Comment: @Karamafrooz I didn't mean worse I meant more complicated.

Comment: @rippergr I can't see how is calling a single method that abstracts away what you are struggling to do in your question or in your posted answer more complicated?

Comment: @I believe I have more control on debug with this code. Maybe I am wrong